# jQuery Datatables - select multiple row from different pages

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have implemented jQuery datatables with pagination enabled.I want to select multiple rows via radio buttons from any random pages and want to perform some action on them on a click of a button.

My current implementation  processes the selection of the current page begin viewed but doesn't process the rest.

**I want to process all records form every page at once. Please Help,**

Here's my button click event code:

```
$('#mastersave').click(function() {

    $('#mastertable tr').filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)').each(function() {
        $tr = $(this);
         ..............
         //Do some operations
         ...............

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, get all `input:checked` in your table, use `fnGetNodes` function.

```
var oTable = $('#mastertable').dataTable();

$('#mastersave').click(function() {
    $("input:checked", oTable.fnGetNodes()).each(function(){

          var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");

          //Do some operations

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an update to Data Tables. In DataTables v1.10 the function names have changed. So the `fnGetNodes` function won't work and will give error: `.fnGetNodes is not a function`.
**Use `table.rows().nodes()`** for reference https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().nodes()